# Times series with R and ts function

Tags: r, plot, time-series

I made a script with R to represent time series of my temperatures according to the dates.
It works well but I am not satisfied with the graphical representation at the end.

My goal is to select a time window, for example from the date 2017-04-01 to the date 2017-04-30 and to represent the daily evolution of my temperatures (so for example 30 graduations in April, 31 in May etc., or dates).

Below my code, and a second code I tried to represent what I want.
Thank you for your help/advices !

```
setwd("C:/XXX")

#Packages
library(ncdf4)
library(stringr)
library(Rcpp)
library(plyr)
library(lubridate)
library(ggplot2)

#My file
nc <-nc_open("NOAA_SST_2017_Corse.nc")

print(nc)

#Variables
lon <- ncvar_get(nc, "lon")
dim(lon)
lat <- ncvar_get(nc, "lat")
dim(lat)
time1 = ncvar_get(nc, "time")
time = as_date(time1,tz="UTC",origin = "1800-01-01")
dim(time)

#Spatial zoom
lonIdx <- which( lon >= 8.4 & lon <= 9.7)
latIdx <- which( lat >= 41.3 & lat <= 43.1)
levelIdx <- 1:length(time)

#dataframe
data_temp<-ncvar_get(nc, "sst")[lonIdx, latIdx, levelIdx]
indices <- expand.grid(lon[lonIdx], lat[latIdx], time[levelIdx])
df <- data.frame(cbind(indices, as.vector(data_temp)))
colnames(df)<-c("longitude","latitude","time","temperature")


View(df)

Final1 = df

write.table(df,"NOAA_SST_2017_Corse")

##removeNA
df2 = na.omit(df)

##daily mean
Final1 <- tapply(df2$temperature,df2$time,mean)
Final1 = as.data.frame(Final1)
View(Final1)
colnames(Final1) = "temperature"
Final2 = as.data.frame(cbind("time"=rownames(Final1),"temperature"=Final1$temperature))
Final2
View(Final2)

> head(Final2)
        jour     temp
1 2017-01-01 15.88318
2 2017-01-02 15.81000
3 2017-01-03 15.85045
4 2017-01-04 15.86500
5 2017-01-05 15.73000
6 2017-01-06 15.45773

> tail(Final2)
          jour     temp
360 2017-12-26 14.02045
361 2017-12-27 13.89318
362 2017-12-28 13.81000
363 2017-12-29 13.89091
364 2017-12-30 13.96409
365 2017-12-31 14.04682

#data?
class(Final2$temperature)
class(Final2$time)

#change variables names
names(Final2)[1]<-"jour"
names(Final2)[2]<-"temp"

#change variable
Final2$temp<-as.character(Final2$temp)

##change variable to numeric class
Final2$temp<-as.numeric(Final2$temp)

class(Final2$temp)
class(Final2$jour)
> class(Final2$temp)
[1] "numeric"
> class(Final2$jour)
[1] "factor"

#time series creation
ts.stt<-ts(data = Final2$temp, start=c(2017,04),frequency = 365.25)

#graphe
install.packages("itsmr")
library(itsmr)
windows()
plotc(ts.stt)
```

And the second code I tried below

```
plot(Final2$jour, Final2$temp, type = "l", xaxt = "n", xlab = "",
     ylab = "SST moyenne/jour", col = "royalblue3")
axis.POSIXct(1, at = seq(Final2$jour[1], tail(Final2$jour, 1), "date"),
             format = "%y/%m/%d", las = 2)

Error in del/by : argument non numérique pour un opérateur binaire
De plus : Warning message:
In Ops.factor(to, if (int) as.double(from) else from) :
  ‘-’ not meaningful for factors
```

Comment: Why is ```class(Final2$jour)``` "factor"? Shouldn't it be Date?